# how commit and push all changes in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

i have created a branch in remote and branch in locally( `git checkout -b gopinath`)

after that i followed the below steps

0)git remote add upstream [your bitbucket repository url goes here.

1) git init

2) git status

3) git add .

4) git commit -m "initial commit"

after giving the 4th command i am getting this issue

`atal: The current branch gopinath has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
    git push --set-upstream origin gopinath`

> why i am getting this issue i am doing the wright way to push my code to bitbucket.

if i checkout to master and deleted the branch locally i am getting this error msg

> Your name and email address were configured automatically based
>   on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
>   You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:
>       git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>       git config --global user.email you@example.com
>   After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

8 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)`

update

`git branch -a` after this i got `*master`

`git remote -v` for this i get
`upstream   https://gopinath123@bitbucket.org/mobinius/ionicpoc.git (fetch)
upstream    https://gopinath123@bitbucket.org/mobinius/ionicpoc.git (push)`

`git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` i get this

`* 5c12918 (HEAD -> master) keychain demo
* 8b518a4 Initial commit`

Comment: Have you added the remote repository URL in git `git remote add origin your_gitrepo_url`?

Comment: you need add remote repository git remote add origin(upstream) repo_url

Comment: yes i have added that one @IvanSheigets

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz after adding the remote origin i am getting 
`fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: You're not showing all commands you have executed, are you? Other point: I think you got the error after a push command, correct?

Comment: no after the commit command as you see in my question

Comment: Why are you doing a `git init` in your repo - this will effectively overwrite your git repo to an empty state... your branch that you created will be deleted

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: i am new to this can you guid me where i should start from and procedure @code_fodder

Comment: What are you trying to do? - just clone a repo (from some remote place) then checkout a branch, make some changes and then push them back up?

Comment: Why do you have to add the remote? Did you clone your repository from bitbucket? Have you commits on bitbucket already? Did you create a fresh and empty repository locally? Please elaborate on what you're doing and why since your process seems to be wrong.

Comment: ok it seems you need to add your username and email again in git after that try commiting your code again

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i have not clone my bitbucket repo and no i am new to this and no i have not created any locall repo and i have a project in my bitbucket repo i have created an branch and in my local also i have created and then as you see i have done above steps that's it

Comment: @code_fodder `git push origin gopinath` i am getting this error msg `error: src refspec gopinath does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'`\

Comment: You can see your branches using `git branch -a` and your remotes using `git remote -v`. Can you run those commands and put the output in your question. Also probably worth doing a `git log --graph --all --decorate --oneline` and put the out put in the question so we can see what is going on (and also may as well put the output of status while you are there : )

Comment: check my updated question @code_fodder

Comment: Also you write step 0 as this: "0)git remote add upstream [your bitbucket repository url goes here" what exactly did you enter as the command? - it should be `git remote add <origin> <url>` lets say <origin> = "upstream" like in your command then you need to do `git push upstream gopinath`

Comment: git remote add orgin <url> @code_fodder

Comment: Hmm....are you sure, your git remote command output tells me that you created a remote called "upstream" not "origin"...does not matter too much. But try the push command "git push upstream gopinath"....infact, I'll write an answer for you now..... hang on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not got a local branch called anything at the moment except one called master (default).

So first create the branch:

```
git branch gopinath
```

Now check it out (move onto that branch)

```
git checkout gopinath
```

Now make some changes if you want and add them:

```
touch newfile
git add newfile
```

now you can commit these changes

```
git commit -m "added a file called newfile"
```

Now you can push these to your remote (which is called "upstream")

```
git push upstream gopinath
```

That should get you there...
It might be worth removing the remotes that you have and re-creating them called "origin" since this is a sort of standard name for the original repo location... let me know if you need to do that Ill add the commands.

Comment: actully i deleted my branch so only i have it is not shown but now i tried and created the branch and i am getting this issue after the commit command

Comment: `Your name and email address were configured automatically basedon your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:
    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com
After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:
    git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: That's ok - its just a warning, but you can do what it suggests to get rid of it. It is saying it does not know who you are so when it adds your details to the commit it uses your username. So literally run the commands `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` and `git config --global user.email you@example.com` and you should be sorted for future commits

Comment: if i checkout to master i am getting this error error: src refspec gopinath does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Comment: You do not have a remote called "origin" you called it "upstream" : o

Comment: after giveing `git push upstream gopinath` i'm getting this error `To https://bitbucket.org/mobinius/ionicpoc.git
 ! [rejected]          gopinath -> gopinath (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gopinath123@bitbucket.org/mobinius/ionicpoc.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: That is also ok.... it means that the remote location "upstream" has been modified by someone else. You can't push your changes because you would effectively be asking the remote side to merge - which it won't allow. So you need to merge in the changes locally by doing "git pull upstream gopinath". But wait...maybe instead of createing the branch locally called gopinath - did you mean to get it remotely? i.e. by doing `git checkout -b gopinath upstream/gopinath`? if so then you can delete your local branch and get the latest from the upstream. If you need to do that Ill update the answer

Comment: i understood the problem the problem was i have creted an branch named gopinath in my bitbucket also and i have created a branch in my local also that was the issue once i delete the file in bitbucket i was able to do all the stuffs thanks

Comment: Yes I think instead of `git checkout -b gopinath` you meant to do `git checkout -b gopinath upstream/gopinath`

Answer (score 0):

Commit the files you changed to your personal repository from the command line.
From a terminal window

```
cd website
git commit -m "Website changes"
git push -u origin master
```